# How can I add extra bottom spacing in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When using `FloatingActionButton` in conjunction with a `ListView`, it hides part of the UI of the `ListView` entries, as seen in the screenshot.
Is there a way to automatically add extra spacing at the bottom of a `ListView` so that the + button does not hide any content?

[image]

Comment: Then there will be completely empty space at your bottom, let say you FAB is of size 60, then from the bottom whole 60 is empty which is even weirder.

Comment: you can move the FAB, a little to the left so it does not hide the buttons, or end the listView at the end of the FAB

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), there is a very nice and simple solution to this.
You probably do *not* want to add padding around the `ListView` itself as that would make some area of your UI unused.

`ListView` has a[`padding` parameter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BoxScrollView/padding.html) for exactly this use case. You can essentially add some padding to the bottom of your `ListView` that is part of the **scrollable area**. This means that you will only start seeing this padding once you have scrolled all the way to the bottom. This will allow you to drag the last few items above the `FloatingActionButton`.
To find an appropriate value for the padding, you can make use of [`kFloatingActionButtonMargin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/kFloatingActionButtonMargin-constant.html) and [`_kExtendedSizeConstraints`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1427fef8f8ce525ef3c0e369f85849243b3a4767/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/floating_action_button.dart#L29), which is not accessible, thus, I will just use `48` like this.

This means that you will want to add the following to your `ListView`:

```dart
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kFloatingActionButtonMargin + 48),
  ..
)
```

Here is a working example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kFloatingActionButtonMargin + 48),
        itemCount: 23,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              trailing: Text('$index'),
            )),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  )));
}
```

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Great job dear!

Answer (score 1):

Expandable(
ListView.builder(
...
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:  200),
...
)
)